# Load linux kernel module from local folder on boot time

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian, kernel-module, beagleboneblack

I am currently working on a project where I created a kernel module to interact with some external hardware. Up to now I always rebuilt and loaded it with a script during the system was running. Now, I am searching for a possibility to load this module during boot time. As this module might still be extended, I still have it in my local delevelopment folder. How can I link or reference this module to be loaded from a users home folder? I already tried to setup the path to the .ko-file in /etc/modules but this didn't work, also my dmesg output does not mention anything about it. Thank you all in advance

(btw, I working with debian (wheezy I think) on my beaglebone black, kernel 3.14.22-ti-r31)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps do
    `/bin/insmod /home/yourname/path/modulename.ko`
in `etc/rc.local`

Comment: Thank you for your input, this should work too, but I was searching for a more generic way to solve this. like tell the kernel where to search for specific modules than pass it via userspace scripts

Comment: The generic way to solve it is to copy the module to /etc/modules and use depmod to make it loadable by modprobe.  You could do it in a more complex way, but why?

Comment: Thank you, I just want to make my module loadable from inside my home directory, so whatever that I change or extend my module, I want it to get loaded dynamically at the next start up in the most recent condition.

Comment: (untried) perhaps you could add a symlink in /etc/modules that points into your home?

Comment: Hi all, after spending too much time on this, I am fine with the first solution Jasen mentioned. Thank you all